# Is an AssetURL guaranteed to be unique on a device?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, icloud

Currently with iCloud, it is possible for a user with iTunes Match to swipe to delete a track, or download a new track from iCloud.

Is it guaranteed that the AssetURL of a track will not be used again on the same device?

I ask as im creating my own cache of the library meta data. When I detect a change to the library, rather than rebuilding my entire cache, id like to be able to just detect removed tracks and newly added ones, and update my cache accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a large enough number to be unique on a device for most intents and purposes. If anyone can confirm this I will change the accepted answer.